# How do I check if a row already exists in my table?

Tags: php, database, forms, validation, error-handling

In my database I have the following `team` table:

| id | name | coach | id_category | id_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | team1 | coach1 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | team2 | coach2 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | team3 | coach3 | 1 | 6 |

I have a form for inserting a new row with each of this fields (except id->auto_increment). The form already has some validations such as checking if the fields are empty and if so, displaying an error. But in `id_category` and `id_level` foreign key columns I want to add a validation that ensures that there will not be **matching rows** in the table for these both columns, for example, I want to add a team with `id_category` "5" and `id_level` "2" but as there's already a row with these two values so I would display a form validation error.

That being said, how can I check if there are matching rows for `id_category` and `id_level` in this table?

*Please provide the code in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a SQL query to check for matching rows in the team table for id_category and id_level. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM team 
WHERE id_category = :id_category 
AND id_level = :id_level
```

In this example, `:id_category` and `:id_level` are placeholders for the values you want to check against. You can use this query to count the number of matching rows, and then use the result to determine whether to display a form validation error.